# Year End Taxes for Property Sale

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, capital-gains-tax

My grandmother & grandfather *(who are now divorced if that matters)* purchased a 5 acre lot in Texas in the 1980's for $30,000. In 2017 my grandmother signed her portion of the deed over to me and in 2020 my grandfather signed his portion of the deed over to me making me 100% owner of the property. If relevant, there is no house on the lot.

I just recently sold the property and have a few questions about the taxes that I will have to pay at end year. Since the property was signed over to me, I'm not sure if this actually qualifies as 'Inheritance' or if this falls under a different category (like maybe gifts?).

This month the property sold for 130,000 so how do I estimate the taxes owed at year end?

- Since half of the property was given to me over a year ago and the other half was given to me this year, will this be categorized as **Short Term** or **Long Term** gains?
- Since the property was signed over to me in full, is 100% of the sale price considered my capital gains? Or is the gains just the difference between initial purchase vs sale price *(130K - 30K)*? Or is the gains the difference between value when I became owner vs the value at time of sale? Again, since each portion of the deed was signed over to me at different times, how will this be determined?
- I did not homestead the property since I live/work in a different city hours away so I don't qualify for any tax breaks that would be applicable in those circumstances.

Comment: I highly recommend getting your account last involved; this is part of what is called “basis”, as in “figuring out your basis” for taxation purposes. There are all kinds of special cases with real estate and familial transfers. Might not be the time for Internet advice from strangers.